# Allow for non-Imgur hosted images in community ads

Tags: feature-request, imgur, community-promotion-ads

Once upon a time, Mi Yodeya had a community ad which looked like this:

[image: Current Mi Yodeya bounties]

This was a really neat ad, and was heavily upvoted and put into the rotation year after year...until however long ago it's been now that non-imgur pictures are banned.

Can this be reversed? If the community wants these kinds of ads which aren't stills, why shouldn't they be able to have it? SE has the final say on if ads can go on rotation, and the fact that they have vetoed ads in the past indicates that they *do* regularly monitor what community ads are on rotation, so if it's one of increased moderation, at least from my completely uninformed and superficial perspective as a user it doesn't seem like there's any loss there.

Comment: The exception for that ad still exists (for example, check out this year's ads on [apple.se]): https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3716

Comment: I'm about to vote to close this since the specific part about the bounty ad is answered there. If you can point out cases *other* than that ad that would warrant this feature as written, please [edit] this to do so. Otherwise, I'll vote this as a dupe since this is essentially answered there.

Comment: @muru I just tried creating that on Code Review, and it wasn't allowed. Something fishy is going on.

Comment: And yes, I know how it works. I managed to do it successfully in [2018](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8616/52915). This year, no luck.